# Is there a way to get description value from a string parameter in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to get the text inside `description` of a string param and use it while sending out a slack notification.
Right now I have something like:

```
properties([parameters([
       string(name: 'TEST_LIST', defaultValue: '12', description: 'Home Page'),
       string(name: 'TEST_LIST', defaultValue: '18', description: 'Login Page')
])
pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron('''
                     30 10 * * 1-5 %TEST_LIST=12
                     30 11 * * 1-5 %TEST_LIST=18
                 ''')])

def listId = params.TEST_LIST.toInteger() //outputs:12

slackSend channel: "#myChannel", message: "Test's for list ${listId} passed. ." //Works well and prints out 12
```

I would instead like it to be something like `Test's for Home Page passed`

I have read through the documentation around [declarative pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-parameters), and it doesn't look like I can not use the description field directly. I would like to try if there are any suggestions from others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look in the parameterizedCron [sourcecode](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/341f012ee33142bee71bbc24acc82365970b5b56/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/parameterizedscheduler/ParameterParser.java), it seems something like this should work; but I have not tested it. I changed the two string parameters to one choice, due to it looks like you only want one test to be ran at any time?

Example:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(name: 'CHOICES', choices: ['12. Home Page', '18. Login Page'], description: 'Select Test List')
  }
  triggers {
    parameterizedCron('''
         30 10 * * 1-5 %CHOICES=12. Home Page;
         30 11 * * 1-5 %CHOICES=18. Login Page;
    ''')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script { 
          def listIdAndName = params.CHOICES.split('.')
          def listId = listIdAndName[0]
          def listName = listIdAndName[1]
          slackSend channel: "#myChannel", message: "Test's for: '${listName}' passed. ."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```